# On button click we are get empty data in text box using asp.net

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, model-view-controller

On button click we are get the data from the database that data i need to display in the text field but it showing null value.

```
$("#btnClick").click(function () {
                var id = jQuery('[id$=hfCustomer]').val();
                $.get("GenericName_Bind", { ProductID: id }, function (data) {
                    $('#txtGenericName').val(data);
                });
```

[image: null]

```
public JsonResult GenericName_Bind(string ProductID)
        {
            PrescriptionBind generic = new PrescriptionBind();
            DataSet ds = generic.Get_GenericName(ProductID);
            List<SelectListItem> statelist = new List<SelectListItem>();
            foreach (DataRow dr in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
            {
                statelist.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = dr["GenericName"].ToString(), Value = dr["GenericID"].ToString() });
            }
            return Json(statelist, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
        #endregion

 public DataSet Get_GenericName(string ProductID)
        {
            SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("Select * from ProductMaster where ProductID=@ProductID", product);
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProductID", ProductID);
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(com);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            da.Fill(ds);
            return ds;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally i found the answer

```
 $("#btnClick").click(function () {
                var id = jQuery('[id$=hfCustomer]').val();
                $.get("GenericName_Bind", { ProductID: id }, function (data) {
                    $.each(data, function (i, v1) {

                        $('#txtGenericName').val(v1.Text);
                    });

                });
            });
```

Comment: That makes no sense - your keep overwriting the value of the textbox (and why on earth is your method returning a `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>`)

Comment: @StephenMuecke  can you share full code please..in my god is working but wrong way I think so please help me

Comment: I don't really know what your wanting to actually display, but you should be returning just one single property (the one you want to display), not a collection of `SelectListItem`, for example `return Json('xxx', JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);` would display `xxx` in textbox using your original code. (assuming your query returns just one record, then it would be `ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["GenericName"]` (but it might be time to consider EF (most of the world stop using DataSets10 years ago)

Comment: @StephenMuecke yes in code is totally worng first i tried to get value and display dropdown list it's working for me that's why am using that way the i try to same code in texbox it's working for me .. so can you clear my code please